# How to open an Office file in the client software programatically in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-hosted-app, angularjs

I have a Sharepoint hosted app that retreive documents from a library and I want that the name of the file has a link to open the document directly to the client Office app. The SP hosted app is made with angular 2 and I am working with REST.

The endpoint i'm using for get the files is:

```
_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Documentos')/items?$select=FileRef,Title&$filter=ContentType eq '" + cttypeName + "'";
```

Is there a property in the file that has that url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using the [Office URI Schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx) in the url, and change the window to it.

```
window.location.href = "ms-word:ofe|u|https://testing.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/doculib/Folder/worddocument.docx";
```

Upon testing, it worked for me.